# I am trying to combine LSTM and CNN in a multi-input model, but a shape error occurs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am implementing a multi-input model while reading a book. This model combines CNN and LSTM.

The input of CNN and the input of LSTM are different. So, of course, the shapes must be different. Is there a way to fit the shapes without affecting the data values ​​??

Or is it that the input shape must be the same for input?

I don't know how to combine. Any help would be appreciated.

**CNN MODEL**

```
with K.tf_ops.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(64,64,1))
    x= layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu')(input_tensor)
    x= layers.Conv2D(128 ,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu')(x)
    x= layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
    x= layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x= layers.Conv2D(256 ,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu')(x)
    x= layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
    x= layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x= layers.Conv2D(512 ,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu')(x)
    x= layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
    x= layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x= layers.Flatten()(x)
    x= layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x= layers.Dense(512,activation='relu')(x)
    x= layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    last_1= layers.Dense(20,activation='softmax')(x)


max_word = 33
max_len =107
nb_classes = 20
```

**LSTM**

```
with K.tf_ops.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    input_tensor_LSTM = Input(shape=(None,),dtype='int32',name='permission')
    x_2=layers.Embedding(max_word,64,input_length=max_len)(input_tensor_LSTM)
    x_2=layers.LSTM(60,return_sequences= True)(x_2)
    x_2=layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(x_2)
    x_2= layers.Dropout(0.5)(x_2)
    x_2= layers.Dense(50,activation='relu')(x_2)
    x_2= layers.Dropout(0.5)(x_2)
    last_2= layers.Dense(20,activation='softmax')(x_2)


merged_model = concatenate([last_1, last_2])
last = layers.Dense(20,activation='softmax')(merged_model)

model = Model([input_tensor,input_tensor_LSTM],last) 

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_dir = './model'
if not os.path.exists(model_dir):
    os.mkdir(model_dir)
model_path = model_dir + "/concatenate.model"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=model_path, monitor="val_loss", verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20)

history = model.fit([X_train_CNN,X_train], y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2, 
callbacks=[checkpoint, early_stopping])
```

The code shown at the top is the model I implemented, and when I use the fit function, the following error appears.

-> Error when checking target: expected dense_89 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (3686, 20, 2)

Comment: what's the shape of y_train? the concatenation seems correct considering the dimensionality... your output layer simply doesn't match your target

Comment: @MarcoCerliani 
Thank you very much. Since I didn't set Y_train, the shape of LSTM data is different, so I modified the shape the same now.
All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(3711, 64, 64, 1), (3686, 107)]

I am having a problem like this, but I am entering two different models, how should I make the shapes the same ??

Comment: the problem is because 3686 !=  3711. Try to review the process where you  build your data

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you !!!!! >____<